# Big Query to Extract data for last one year

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I need to extract data from big query for one year provided it should take data for past 12 months from last day of the last month for example todays date is 27/10/2022 .It should extract data from 01/10/2021 to 30/9/2022.

I tried WHERE DATE(xyz) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE().
Its taking from current date but i need it 12 months past from last day of previous month

Answer (score 0):

The last day of last month can be calculated by

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
+---------------------------------------------+
| LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2022-09-30                                  |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

To specify the beginning of the period, subtract 13 MONTH instead of 1 MONTH and add one day:

```
... WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 13 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: Can you please help me to get the range